# Laravel 4 routes and register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

i have a register form that has a refer inmput, in my web for example myweb.com/registro i make a new register, but i need to create a refer link to refer users, my url should myweb.com/nombredeusuario and make a form with the refer input = nombredeusuario

I use:

```
Route::get('registro/{name?}',function($name = null)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }

    return View::make('registro')->with('user', $name);
});
```

But i need to make this in the home url the refer link has to be myweb.com/username
if the link dont have nothing myweb.com do return View::make('home');
and if not myweb.com/something make a form with the refer input = something can i do that?

Thanks!! Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, just add another `if`, and render the register view if `$name` is set

```
Route::get('registro/{name?}',function($name = false){

    // If user us logged in, redirect to Dashboard
    if(Auth::check())
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');

    // if $name is set, return the register view
    if($name)
        return View::make('register', ['referrer' => $name]);

    // If no $name and no Auth(), return the default home view
    return View::make('home'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a home route with a optional register:

```
Route::get('{name?}',function($name = null)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }

    if ( ! $name || ! User::where('username', $name)->first())
    {
        return View::make('home');
    }

    return View::make('registro')->with('user', $name);
});
```

So if you hit, or the user does not exists

```
myweb.com
```

You'll see the home. And if you hit

```
myweb.com/antoniocarlos
```

You'll see the register page.